# creating the directory with the month name only

Tags: command-line, date

Posting question by curiosity,
I wanted to create directory like January, February...to December so I created  them by individually giving the name. ( `mkdir January February` ....etc)
Is it possible to create directories or filenames with the name of all the months in easy manner?

for example : `touch {1..10}` will create 10 files 1,2,3...10 easily, like this is there any other solution to create the files or directory with month name?

Answer (score 18):

POSIXly,

```
(IFS=';'; set -f; mkdir -- $(locale mon))
```

Note, that it's the month names in the current language. Replace with `LC_ALL=C locale mon` if you want the English ones regardless of the language of the user.

With `zsh`, you can also use the `$langinfo` special associative array (in the `zsh/langinfo` module):

```
zmodload zsh/langinfo
eval mkdir -- '$langinfo[MON_'{1..12}']'
```

Though

```
mkdir -- ${(s:;:)"$(locale mon)"}
```

would be shorter. In `rc`/`es` which are other shells with splitting operators where you can specify the separators (other than via that global `$IFS` setting like in Bourne-like shells):

```
mkdir -- ``';'{locale mon}
```

Answer (score 9):

Modification of [heemayl's script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/302204/89144)

```
for i in {1..12} ; do
   mkdir $(LC_TIME=C date +%B -d "${i}/15")
done
```

Without loop

```
LC_TIME=C date +%B -f <(printf "%d/15\n" {1..12}) | xargs mkdir
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use a looping construct with GNU `date` which takes `+1 month`, `+2 months` like inputs:

```
i=1; while ((i<=12)); do mkdir "$(date -d "+$i month" '+%B')"; ((i++)); done
```

**Example:**

```
$ i=1; while ((i<=12)); do date -d "+$i month" '+%B'; ((i++)); done
September
October
November
December
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
```

Comment: Set i to 5 at the start to start from jan.

Comment: @123 Say it again 22 days ;)

Answer (score 4):

Python knows all the names of the months:

```
mkdir $(python -c 'import calendar; print(" ".join(calendar.month_name))')
```

Or, we can use python directly to make the directory :

```
python -c 'import calendar,locale,os;locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "");[os.mkdir(m) for m in calendar.month_name if m]'
```

The heart of the above is `[os.mkdir(m) for m in calendar.month_name if m]` which makes a directory for every month in `calendar.month_name`.  This will generate an error message and quit if any of the directories already exist.  If we want to avoid that, we can test for the directories existence before calling `mkdir`:

```
python -c 'import calendar,os;[os.mkdir(m) for m in calendar.month_name if m and not os.path.exists(m)]'
```

#### Example:

```
$ python -c 'import calendar,os;[os.mkdir(m) for m in calendar.month_name if m]'
$ ls
April   December  January  June   May       October
August  February  July     March  November  September
```

#### Internationalization

Stéphane Chazelas points out that the above prints English month names.  To get local month names, he suggests:

```
python -c 'import calendar,locale,os;locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "");[os.mkdir(m) for m in calendar.month_name if m]'
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. I updated the answer.  (Your `locale mon` is superior and already has my +1.)

Answer (score 2):

Using locales and assuming Linux (the output of `locale(1)` is different on other systems) and `bash(1)`:

```
#! /bin/sh
(
    eval "$( locale -k -c LC_TIME | grep ^mon= )" || exit
    IFS=\; months=($mon)
    mkdir "${months[@]}"
)
```

Comment: `months=($mon)` is not `sh` syntax. That's `ksh93` or `bash` syntax.